# In Python how do I use list comprehensions to iterate through a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples with values and co-ordinates of 11 points

```
dotted_array = [(0, 0, '.'), (2, 0, '.'), (3, 0, '.'), (0, 1, '.'), (2, 1, '.'), (0, 2, '.'), (2, 2, '.'), (3, 2, '.'), (0, 3, '.'), (2, 3, '.'), (3, 3, '.')]
```

I have a list of 5 lists:

```
list_of_signs = [['+', '+', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+', '-', '+', '+', '-'], ['+', '+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '+', '-', '+', '+', '-'], ['+', '+', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+', '-', '+', '+', '-'], ['+', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+', '-', '+', '+', '-'], ['+', '+', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+', '-', '+', '+', '-']]
```

Each list in that list consists of i values of +/-. These +/- values correspond to the new value of the list element in dotted_array.

```
list_of_signs[] = [+,-,+,-,+.....11 values in each 'list_of_signs[]']
```

This is the expected output by combining the 'value' from list_of_signs[] and co-ordinates from dotted_array[]

```
coord_list = [[(0, 0, '+'), (2, 0, '+'), (3, 0, '-'), (0, 1, '+'), (2, 1, '+'), (0, 2, '+'), (2, 2, '+'), (3, 2, '-'), (0, 3, '+'), (2, 3, '+'), (3, 3, '-')], 4 More such lists ]
```

Currently I am:

```
coord_list= [(x[0],x[1],list_of_signs[0][0]) for x in dotted_array]
```

To get:

```
[(0, 0, '+'), (2, 0, '+'), (3, 0, '+'), (0, 1, '+'), (2, 1, '+'), (0, 2, '+'), (2, 2, '+'), (3, 2, '+'), (0, 3, '+'), (2, 3, '+'), (3, 3, '+')]
```

This output is not only wrong, but also not general.
How do I generalize this for all list_of_signs?

Comment: Can you give a valid input for both arrays and the expected output for that?

Comment: Please edit to include the full array definitions. The answer is trivial, but inventing your full code from the description is not.

Comment: @o11c Please check the edit as it now has valid input and expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want? -

```
>>> dotted_array = [(1,2,'.'), (4,5,'.'),(1,2,'.'), (4,5,'.'),(1,2,'.'), (4,5,'.')]
>>> list_of_signs = [['+','-','-','+','+','-'],['-','-','+','+','+','-']]


>>> coord_list = [[(x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1]) for x in zip(dotted_array,s)] for s in list_of_signs]


>>> coord_list
[[(1, 2, '+'), (4, 5, '-'), (1, 2, '-'), (4, 5, '+'), (1, 2, '+'), (4, 5, '-')], [(1, 2, '-'), (4, 5, '-'), (1, 2, '+'), (4, 5, '+'), (1, 2, '+'), (4, 5, '-')]]
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function combines the lists it receives as parameter at each index so ith index of returned list(or iterator) of zip would be a tuple of ith element of first array and then ith element of second array , so on.

Comment: Sorry , if you are asking what is `>>>` its just the python interpreter's prompt.

Comment: Got it. It appeared as though it was inside your list comprehension.

Comment: I would use tuple unpacking in the for instead of writing `x[0][0]` etc.

Comment: might look a little cleaner to use a pattern match instead of indexes ie `coord_list = [[(a,b,op) for ((a,b,_), op) in zip(dotted_array, l)] for l in list_of_signs]`

Comment: Since you also have ones in your list comprehension, would you consider refactoring the variable 'l' as an 's' for signs. I was trying to figure out why it was zip(dotted_array, 1). :-)

Comment: @AMR done, sorry didn't realize using `l` would make it hard to read.

Comment: @mehtunguh...your expression looks more readable to me .. nice .. :)

Comment: @AnandSKumar, you probably have younger eyes... The older you get the more you have to zoom in!

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it works:

```
dotted_array = [(1,2,'.'), (4,5,'.')]
list_of_signs = [['+','-'],['-','-']]

coord_list = []
for idx1, list_of_sign in enumerate(list_of_signs):
    mylist = []
    for idx2, tup in enumerate(dotted_array):
        mylist += [(tup[0],tup[1],list_of_signs[idx1][idx2]) ]
    coord_list += mylist

print coord_list
```

Writing that in one line would be fun.

Give a valid input for both arrays and the expected output for that.

Comment: `for sign in list_of_sign:` are you assuming `sign` would be index?

Comment: notice the op asked for list comprehensions, but this solution uses a for loop.

Comment: @sinhayash According to my input data, your solution appends the values from the list_of_signs to the co-ordinates in the dotted_array, 55 times resulting in 605 outputs. My question before the edits was probably not clear.

Comment: Question is changed. Anyway You have got the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
dotted = zip(range(1,22,2),range(2,23,2),'.'*11)
signs = ['+-+-+-+-+-+']*5
print [(dotted[n][:-1]+(i,)) for s in signs for n,i in enumerate(s)]
```